# MSSQL Backup Immediately Suspended [BULKOP_BACKUP_DB]

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-backups, sql-server-agent, maintenance-plan

Our production database server has stopped running the backup maintance plans...

The server has plenty of space, upon googling and futher investigation it appears the backups are being halted they moment they are started.

Running "Select * from Sys.dm_Exec_requests where command = 'Backup Database'" indicates the backup is being suspended due to 'DATABASE: 5 [BULKOP_BACKUP_DB]' with wait type of 'LCK_M_U'

I have tried searching for an answer to this, but nothing seems to apply in this case.

As i stated the server has plenty of disk space, and has been restarted, yet the backups are still immediatly suspened.

I'm all out of ideas, and would apreciate any input into helping me fix this 'issue'

Update: It seems it is waiting for session 77 to finish which is another backup, but it is 'Killed/Rollback' with percentage complete of 76% (doesnt appear to be changing) and a wait time of 267328092, trying to kill this prcoess results in 'SPID 77: transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 76%. Estimated time remaining: 86124 seconds.'

Update: Upon installing updates, trying some fixes, it appeared fixed, however on its second attempt it also stopped processing the backup, this time with a wait type of ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION...

any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like it's time to give Microsoft a call...